# Why is this Swing Timer code is throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to animate an ellipse in Java using a Swing Timer.  I believe the following code should do the job, but when I run my program, the timer throws a `NullPointerException`.  Any idea as to why that may be?

I've excluded the code with the mainline as it isn't relevant.  Here is my error, which is occurrs the first line in the `actionlistener`'s `actionperformed` method:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Timer$MoveListener.actionPerformed(Timer.java:18)
```

Panel Class:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Glitchpanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Ellipse ellipse;
    private java.awt.Dimension size;
    private Timer timer;

    public Glitchpanel() {
        super();

        ellipse = new Ellipse();
        size = new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000);
        timer = new Timer(ellipse, this);
        timer.start();

        this.setSize(size);
        this.setPreferredSize(size); 
        this.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
}

    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        java.awt.Graphics2D brush = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
        brush.draw(ellipse);
    }
}
```

Timer Class:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Timer extends javax.swing.Timer {

    private Glitchpanel glitch;
    private Ellipse ellipse;

    public Timer(Ellipse ellipse, Glitchpanel glitch) {
        super(100, null);
        ellipse = ellipse;
        glitch = glitch;
        this.addActionListener(new MoveListener());
    }

    private class MoveListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            ellipse.setX(ellipse.getX()+1);
            ellipse.setY(ellipse.getY()+1);
            glitch.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Shape Class (Trying to animate this object):

```
public class Ellipse extends java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double {

    private Glitchpanel glitch;
    private double x, y, w, h;

    public Ellipse() {
        super();

        double x = 100;
        double y = 100;
        double w = 100;
        double h = 100;
        this.setFrame(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void setX(double x2) {
        x = x2;
    }

    public void setY(double y2) {
        y = y2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
public Timer(Ellipse ellipse, Glitchpanel glitch) {
    super(100, null);
    ellipse = ellipse;
    glitch = glitch;
    this.addActionListener(new MoveListener());
}
```

to:

```
public Timer(Ellipse ellipse, Glitchpanel glitch) {
    super(100, null);
    this.ellipse = ellipse;
    this.glitch = glitch;
    this.addActionListener(new MoveListener());
}
```

Comment: I did the above to no avail--still getting the same nullpointer.  Thanks though!

Comment: @user2654199 Exactly the same one really? The bug is that `ellipse` is null. You can get almost the same bug by not setting `glitch` either (I fixed both in the above code)

Comment: i spoke too soon, this fixed it actually.  I appreciate your help!